# how do i get my circuit working using a thermocouple?

Tags: thermocouple

I'm working on some research about SEEBECK EFFECT. is it absolutely necessary to have a gradual CHANGE in temperature at the hot end so as to induce EMF..or can i simply MAINTAIN both cold and hot ends at a fixed temperature

Which 2 metals should I combine to obtain max current ??

Comment: It looks like you should do some research before asking this question, the Wikipedia page would be a good place to start. The seebeck effect is caused by the difference in temperature, so you don't need to change any temperature, as for the 2 metals to choose, there are lots of tables of expected outputs available online, but without knowing what temperatures you're working with, we can't help.

Answer (score 1):

With well-behaved thermocouple alloys, thermal gradients in the midwire
are irrelevant.  Unless you dislike measurement accuracy, though, you 
do NOT want to draw  maximum current from thermocouples, because the inverse of the Seebeck effect is the Peltier effect: current causes heating at
the cooler junction, and cooling of the hotter junction.

If you wish to construct a thermopile (heat-driven generator of electricity)
there are semiconductor Peltier devices that would give good efficiency,
within their allowed temperature range.

Type J thermocouples famously are poorly behaved above 750C, and
DO misbehave if any part, including midwire, gets that hot.